# V8::IdleNotification() never returns true

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

For some reasons, sometimes the call of the IdleNotification never returns true. The documentation states that

> > Optional notification that the embedder is idle. V8 uses the notification to reduce memory footprint. This call can be used
> >     repeatedly if the embedder remains idle. Returns true if the
> >     embedder should stop calling IdleNotification until real work has
> >     been done.  This indicates that V8 has done as much cleanup as it
> >     will be able to do.

So when the IdelNotifcation never returns true, it means that the garbage collector of V8 never finishes its work.

Because I cannot really find the reason for this behavior I would be glad if anybody could give me a hint what might cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `LowMemoryNotification()` on the `Isolate` instead of or before calling `IdleNotification`. The former function informs V8 that it should work to free up memory. Without that memory pressure, it doesn't care about a few bytes that you may have allocated.